# Pure Javascript particle repeller from base64 encoded png

Tags: javascript, debugging, animation, optimization, particle-system

I have some js code that i copied from a youtube tutorial and adapted for my own project to fill the header, the code works as intended and it works when the viewport is smaller than around 1200px, however when i put firefox into full screen the animation does not play & the image is being stretched, not retaining its aspect ratio. I do have a 10/15 year old gpu so i'm guessing thats half my issue. The script uses a png image file of 100x100 pixels, which it then converts into particle color values. Can this be optimized or made to run better. it seems that the wider the viewport the longer the animation takes to kick in, until it finally stops & doesn't work. full screen= [2550x1440]...

The original tutorial is here: [Pure Javascript Particle Animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afdHgwn1XCY&t=711s) & to convert an image to base64 encoding is here: [Image to base64](https://www.base64decode.net).

HTML:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="CanV"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
#Canv{
  position:absolute;
  top:-1px;left:-2px;
  z-index:67;
  width:100vw !important;
  max-height: 264px !important;
  min-height: 245px !important;
  filter:blur(2.27px);
}
```

Javascript:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",(e)=>{
  const canv = document.getElementById('Canv');
  const ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
  canv.width = window.innerWidth;
  canv.height = window.innerHeight/ 3.85;

  let particleArray = [];
  let mouse = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    radius: 74
  }

   window.addEventListener('mousemove',(e)=>{
     mouse.x = event.x + canv.clientLeft/2;
     mouse.y = event.y + canv.clientTop/1.2;
   });

  function drawImage(){
    let imageWidth = png.width;      //These to values crop if / sum no.
    let imageHeight = png.height;
    const data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight); //Gets img data for particles
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canv.width, canv.height); // Clears the original img as its now being stored in the variable data.

    class Particle {
      constructor(x, y, color, size){
        this.x = x + canv.width/2 - png.width * 174,     //Chngd Ok:74
        this.y = y + canv.height/2 - png.height * 32,     //Ch<2  Ok:16
        this.color = color,
        this.size = 2.28, // Particle Size > Changed this value. from 2 i think!.
        this.baseX = x + canv.width/1.8 - png.width * 3.1,  //Chngd ok:5.1
        this.baseY = y + canv.height/1.2 - png.height * 2.8,
        this.density = (Math.random() * 14) + 2;
      }
      draw() {
         ctx.beginPath();  // this creates the sort of force field around the mouse pointer.
         ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
         ctx.closePath();
         ctx.fill();
      }
      update() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;

        // Collision detection
        let dx = mouse.x - this.x;
        let dy = mouse.y - this.y;
        let distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        let forceDirectionX = dx / distance;
        let forceDirectionY = dy / distance;
        // Max distance, past that the force will be 0
        const maxDistance = 144;
        let force = (maxDistance - distance) / maxDistance;
        if (force < 0) force = 0;
        let directionX = (forceDirectionX * force * this.density * 0.6);
        let directionY = (forceDirectionY * force * this.density * 8.7); //Ch.this

        if (distance < mouse.radius + this.size) {
          this.x -= directionX;
          this.y -= directionY;
        } else {
          if (this.x !== this.baseX){
            let dx = this.x - this.baseX;
            this.x -= dx/54;  // Speed Particles return to ori
        } if (this.y !== this.baseY){
          let dy = this.y - this.baseY;
          this.y -= dy/17;  // Speed Particles return to ori
        }
       }
       this.draw();
      }
    }
    function init(){
      particleArray = [];
      for(let y = 0, y2 = data.height; y<y2; y++){
        for(let x =0, x2 = data.width; x<x2; x++){
          if(data.data[(y * 4 * data.width) + (x*4) + 3] > 128){
            let positionX = x + 25;
            let positionY = y + 45; // Co-ords on Canv
            let color = "rgb(" + data.data[(y * 4 * data.width) + (x * 4)] + "," +
                         data.data[(y * 4 * data.width) + (x * 4) + 1] + "," +
                         data.data[(y * 4 * data.width) + (x * 4) + 2] + ")";
            particleArray.push(new Particle(positionX * 2, positionY * 2, color));
          } /* These number effect png size but its to high */
        }
      }
    }
    function animate(){
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,.07)';
      ctx.fillRect(0,0, innerWidth, innerHeight);

      for(let i =0; i < particleArray.length; i++){
        particleArray[i].update();
      }
    }
    init();
    animate();
  }

  const png = new Image();

  png.src = "RemovedBase64StringToBig";

  window.addEventListener('load',(e)=>{
    console.log('page has loaded');
    ctx.drawImage(png, 0, 0);
    drawImage();
  })

});
```

have managed to shorten it by about 100 characters by shortening all the variable names > PartArr, ImgWidth, DirX, DirY etc, but apart from minifying it is there any other ways to optimize this? and fix the full screen issue?

I tried to add it to a JSfiddle, So I could link to it here, but I don't think this is allowing the base64 string, its not loading anything anyway. The canvas loads, with the bg just no image or animation.

I've found out what part of the problem is with full screen, the cursor position is actually about 300px to the right of where the actual cursor is, but I still have no idea how to fix this or fix the major lagging performance issues. Guessing its alot to compute even just with 100x100.

One option I can think of to make this perform better would be to move it & its calculations, into its own dedicated web worker & convert the image to Webp but i'm still not very clued up about web workers or how to implement them properly.. Will play around & see what I can put together using All the suggestions in the comments & answers.

I'm adding these links only for future reference, when I come back to this later on:

[MDN Canvas Optimizations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas)
[Html5Rocks Canvas Performance](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/)
[Stack Question. Canv ~ Opti](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205828/html5-canvas-performance-and-optimization-tips-tricks-and-coding-best-practices)
[Creating A blob From A Base 64 String in Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript?rq=1)

Secondary bonus Question,
is there a maximum file size or max px dimensions,
that can be base64 encoded? only asking this as someone on facebook has recently sent me a question regarding another project with multiple base64 encoded images and I was unsure of the answer..

Comment: Well, it sure does like to eat-up CPU cycles, thats for sure! While you'd have to expect GL to speed it up a bazillion percent, it would also need a fair bit of work. At this stage of the game, it hardly seems premature to remove unnecessary calculations. One of the worst offenders is pixel-access code. 4 values exist for each pixel, rgba. Once you know where the first one is, the rest are just offset from there. Here's an obvious optimization: `let index = ((y*width)+x)*4;` `r = data[index+0]; g = data[index+1];` etc. followed closely with: ``let color = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;``

Comment: Someone else somewhere accessed the canvas pixels as a width X height length array of uint32s, instead of a width X height X 4 array of uint8s. You just do some bit-manipulation to extract the components you want. Though - since you want to use the colour as is, you may find you can extract it as a 4 byte int and then pass the hex version of that as a colour. E.g White pixel - data holds this [255][255][255][255]. You extract as a 32 bit value (4294967295) then convert to a colour thusly let rgb = '#' + value.toString(16);. That will save 3 accesses for each pixel read and is quick to decode.

Comment: Sounds complicated, may have to read through these a couple of times. Not sure i fully understand why its pulling in a width value for a color calculation anyway. but thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Would your code snippet replace the whole 'let colors =' block, i'm guessing.? or the two for loops?

Comment: Would it be possible (whether or not really difficult). to force this to run on the GPU instead of the CPU seeing as thats what their designed for, doing very fast calculations. Or is Canvas codes already doing that?

Comment: Yep, I replaced the `let colors=` block with the single index calc and string literal (string in backticks, variables preceded with a $ and wrapped in curly braces). I'd replace the same part with a 32bit grab from the frame-buffer combined with the ability to specify the radix as a quicker,nastier trick.  That was my first idea - GPU, GPU, GPU. But then I thought about it. Was unsure where the bottle-neck is so profiled it and I discovered about 71% of the time is burned in `arc`, `fill` and `closePath`. :eeeeeek:!

Comment: Tried replacing this but it broke the canvas, could you edit as an answer or play around with it if you have time....

Comment: Here's a discussion about the 'read a whole pixel in one go' trick: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/12/faster-canvas-pixel-manipulation-with-typed-arrays/ I'll have a look later if I get some time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203278/discussion-between-ryan-stone-and-enhzflep).

Comment: Hello @enhzflep, I read through that document you attached and it mentions 'not needing to multiply the data x 4' does that mean in this section::>   if(data.data[(y * 4 * data.width) + (x*4) + 3] > 128){       That I should also remove the (x*4) component, finding it hard to wrap my head around this code...

Comment: Also your code snippet still retains a x4 i'm confused.. lol

Comment: My code just does what yours does. I spoke about single access for pixels, though didn't implement it here. You can see the results of these 2 methods of access and another too, in this performance test suite, found here: https://jsperf.com/canvas-pixel-manipulation

Comment: @RyanStone are you still actively searching for an answer on this?

Comment: @CodeBling Yes it is an Open ended question basically, the more answers and comments recieved the more it helps me learn. & no ones provided an alternative implementation as of yet..

Comment: Looks like the guy that answered before has deleted his answer..

Comment: Sounds good. Half of the new users on SO ask a question and then never come back, so was just checking

Comment: So I set this up and had a look at it and it locked up my box. If this is a virus, you are extremely clever.

Comment: @Codebling, No its not a virus it just takes nearly all your ram and cpu to calculate...

Comment: You can also implement some of this micro-optimization techniques described here: [Bitwise Gems and other optimizations](https://galactic.ink/journal/2011/11/bitwise-gems-and-other-optimizations/)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2**: I have managed to optimize further. Now **it can render FullHD** image (1920x1080) **without downgrading quality** (on my PC it runs at about 20fps).

[Take a look this code on JSFiddle (you can also tweak values).](https://jsfiddle.net/draxcp6/ycv9bn15/8/)

Thanks also goes to [@Richard (check out his answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59092312/pure-javascript-particle-repeller-from-base64-encoded-png/60629888#60629888) for idea to put all data in `ImageData` and make a single draw call. Code on JSFiddle is combination of his and mine optimizations (code below is my old code).

**EDIT:** Updated JSFiddle link, optimized more by spreading work of stationary particles across multiple frames (for given settings it improves performance for about 10%).

---

Regarding optimization, you won't achieve much by minifying code (in this case) because code that eats up CPU is runtime intensive (executes each frame). Minification is good for optimizing loading, not runtime execution.

Most of time is spent on drawing, and after some investigation I have found few performance optimizations but these are not enough to make big difference (eg. `ctx.closePath()` can be omitted and this saves some milliseconds).

What you can do is to either reduce resolution of image or skip some pixels in image in order to reduce work.
Additionally you could spread work across multiple frames to improve frame rate (but keep in mind if you spread it on more than few frames you might start seeing flickering).

Fullscreen issue can be solved by simply re-initializing everything on `resize` event.

Below is code with mentioned optimizations and fullscreen fix. Sample **image is 375x375** pixels.

---

**UPDATE:** I played a little with code and I managed to improve further performance by optimizing calls (things I mentioned below code snippet). Code is updated with these changes.

---

```js
var canv
var ctx

//performance critical parameters
const pixelStep = 2 //default 1; increase for images of higher resolution
const maxParticlesToProcessInOneFrame = 20000

//additional performance oriented paramteres
// Max distance, past that the force will be 0
const maxDistance = 144
const mouseRadius = 74

//customization parameters
const ctxFillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,.07)'
const speedOfActivatingParticle = 1
const speedOfRestoringParticle = 0.1

const png = new Image();


const mouse = {
  x: null,
  y: null
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  mouse.x = event.x + canv.clientLeft;
  mouse.y = event.y + canv.clientTop;
})

class Particle {
  constructor(x, y, size) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.size = pixelStep
    this.baseX = x
    this.baseY = y
    this.density = (Math.random() * 14) + 2
  }
  draw() {
    //ctx.beginPath();  // this creates the sort of force field around the mouse pointer.
    //ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.size * 2, this.size * 2)
    //ctx.closePath();
  }
  update() {
    // Collision detection
    let dx = mouse.x - this.x;
    let dy = mouse.y - this.y;
    let distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    if (distance < mouseRadius + this.size) {
      let forceDirectionX = dx / distance;
      let forceDirectionY = dy / distance;
      let force = (maxDistance - distance) / maxDistance;
      if (force < 0)
        force = 0;
      const forceTimesDensity = force * this.density * speedOfActivatingParticle
      let directionX = (forceDirectionX * forceTimesDensity);
      let directionY = (forceDirectionY * forceTimesDensity); //Ch.this
      this.x -= directionX;
      this.y -= directionY;
    } else {
      if (this.x !== this.baseX) {
        let dx = this.x - this.baseX;
        this.x -= dx * speedOfRestoringParticle; // Speed Particles return to ori
      }
      if (this.y !== this.baseY) {
        let dy = this.y - this.baseY;
        this.y -= dy * speedOfRestoringParticle; // Speed Particles return to ori
      }
    }
    this.draw();
  }
}


window.addEventListener('resize', initializeCanvas)
window.addEventListener("load", initializeCanvas, {
  once: true
})

let animationFrame = null

function initializeCanvas(e) {
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame)

  canv = document.getElementById('Canv');
  ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
  canv.width = window.innerWidth;
  canv.height = window.innerHeight;

  let particles = {}

  function drawImage() {
    let imageWidth = png.width; //These to values crop if / sum no.
    let imageHeight = png.height;
    const data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight); //Gets img data for particles
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height); // Clears the original img as its now being stored in the variable data.

    function init() {
      particles = {}
      for (let y = 0, y2 = data.height; y < y2; y += pixelStep) {
        for (let x = 0, x2 = data.width; x < x2; x += pixelStep) {
          if (data.data[(y * 4 * data.width) + (x * 4) + 3] > 128) {
            let positionX = x
            let positionY = y
            let color = "rgb(" + data.data[(y * 4 * data.width) + (x * 4)] + "," +
              data.data[(y * 4 * data.width) + (x * 4) + 1] + "," +
              data.data[(y * 4 * data.width) + (x * 4) + 2] + ")";
            let particlesArray = particles[color]
            if (!particlesArray)
              particlesArray = particles[color] = []
            particlesArray.push(new Particle(positionX * 2, positionY * 2))
          } /* These number effect png size but its to high */
        }
      }
    }
    let particlesProcessed = 0
    let animateGenerator = animate()

    function* animate() {
      particlesProcessed = 0
      ctx.fillStyle = ctxFillStyle;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);

      let colors = Object.keys(particles)
      for (let j = 0; j < colors.length; j++) {
        let color = colors[j]
        ctx.fillStyle = color
        let particlesArray = particles[color]
        ctx.beginPath()
        for (let i = 0; i < particlesArray.length; i++) {
          particlesArray[i].update()
          if (++particlesProcessed > maxParticlesToProcessInOneFrame) {
            particlesProcessed = 0
            ctx.fill()
            yield
            ctx.beginPath()
          }
        }
        ctx.fill()
      }
    }
    init();

    function animateFrame() {
      animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        if (animateGenerator.next().done) {
          animateGenerator = animate()
        }
        animateFrame()
      })
    }
    animateFrame()
  }

  console.log('page has loaded');
  ctx.drawImage(png, 0, 0, png.width, png.height);
  drawImage();
}



png.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#Canv {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  filter: blur(1.5px);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="Canv"></canvas>
```

If you still need to optimize, you could do some optimization regarding `ctx.beginPath()`, `ctx.fill()` and `ctx.rect()` calls. For example, try to combine sibling pixels (pixels that are next to each other) and render them all in one call. Furthermore, you could merge similar colors in single color, but downside is that image will loose quality (depending on how much colors are merged).

Also (if this is option) you might want to set fixed canvas size rather than dynamically sized.

---

Disclosure: On my PC given code works nicely, but on others it might still have performance issues. For that reason try to play with `pixelStep` and `maxParticlesToProcessInOneFrame` variable values.

Comment: Js Fiddle looks pretty Awesome dude, no lagging still on my old pc & gpu.. Job well done. Wondering who to give the bounty to now...

Comment: Thanks :) If you are wondering what parts of I used from @Ryan's answer - it is that optimization to put all pixels in image before making draw call on canvas. Everything else is pretty much mine. I have updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Shortening your code doesn't help much with performance. I'm using Firefox. To check what's taking your time up the most during browser runs in Firefox, you can read [Performance from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance).

The problem with your solution is your fps is dropping hard. This happens because you are **painting** each **Particle** every frame. Imagine how laggy it will be when there are thousands of Particles that you need to paint every frame. This paint call is called from your function `Particle.draw` (which calls the following: `ctx.beginPath, ctx.arc, and ctx.closePath`). This function, as said, will be called because of `Particle.update` for **each** frame. This is an extremely expensive operation. To improve your fps drastically, you can try to **not** draw each Particle individually, but rather gather all the Particles' [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) wholly then placing it in the canvas only once in `rAQ` (thus only one paint happens). This `ImageData` is an object that contains the `rgba` for each pixel on canvas.

In my solution below, I did the following:

- For each Particle that is dirty (has been updated), modify the `ImageData` that is to be put in the canvas
- Then, after the whole `ImageData` has been constructed for one frame, only draw **once** to the canvas using [`putImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData). This saves a lot of the time needed to call your function `Particle.update` to draw each Particle individually.

One other obvious solution is to increase the size of Particles so that there are fewer Particles' pixels that are needed to be processed (to alter `ImageData`). I've also tweaked the code a little so that the image will always be at least 100px high; you can tweak the maths so that the image will always maintain your aspect ratio and respond to window size.

Here's a working example:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas1')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
let canvasWidth = canvas.width
let canvasHeight = canvas.height
let particleArray = []
let imageData = []

// mouse
let mouse = {
  x: null,
  y: null,
  radius: 40
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  mouse.x = event.x
  mouse.y = event.y
})

function drawImage(width, height) {
  let imageWidth = width
  let imageHeight = height
  const data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight)
  
  class Particle {
    constructor(x, y, color, size = 2) {
      this.x = Math.round(x + canvas.width / 2 - imageWidth * 2)
      this.y = Math.round(y + canvas.height / 2 - imageHeight * 2)
      this.color = color
      this.size = size
      
      // Records base and previous positions to repaint the canvas to its original background color
      this.baseX = Math.round(x + canvas.width / 2 - imageWidth * 2)
      this.baseY = Math.round(y + canvas.height / 2 - imageHeight * 2)
      this.previousX = null
      this.previousY = null
      this.density = (Math.random() * 100) + 2
    }
    
    stringifyColor() {
      return `rgba(${this.color.r}, ${this.color.g}, ${this.color.b}, ${this.color.a}`
    }
    
    update() {
      ctx.fillStyle = this.stringifyColor()
      
      // collision detection
      let dx = mouse.x - this.x
      let dy = mouse.y - this.y
      let distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
      let forceDirectionX = dx / distance
      let forceDirectionY = dy / distance
      
      // max distance, past that the force will be 0
      const maxDistance = 100
      let force = (maxDistance - distance) / maxDistance
      if (force < 0) force = 0
      
      let directionX = (forceDirectionX * force * this.density)
      let directionY = (forceDirectionY * force * this.density)
      
      this.previousX = this.x
      this.previousY = this.y
      if (distance < mouse.radius + this.size) {
        this.x -= directionX
        this.y -= directionY
      } else {
       // Rounded to one decimal number to as x and y cannot be the same (whole decimal-less integer) 
       // as baseX and baseY by decreasing using a random number / 20
        if (Math.round(this.x) !== this.baseX) {
          let dx = this.x - this.baseX
          this.x -= dx / 20
        }
        if (Math.round(this.y) !== this.baseY) {
          let dy = this.y - this.baseY
          this.y -= dy / 20
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  function createParticle(x, y, size) {
    if (data.data[(y * 4 * data.width) + (x * 4) + 3] > 128) {
      let positionX = x
      let positionY = y
      let offset = (y * 4 * data.width) + (x * 4)
      let color = {
        r: data.data[offset],
        g: data.data[offset + 1],
        b: data.data[offset + 2],
        a: data.data[offset + 3]
      }
      
      return new Particle(positionX * 4, positionY * 4, color, size)
    }
  }
  
  // Instead of drawing each Particle one by one, construct an ImageData that can be
  // painted into the canvas at once using putImageData()
  function updateImageDataWith(particle) {
    let x = particle.x
    let y = particle.y
    let prevX = particle.previousX
    let prevY = particle.previousY
    let size = particle.size

    if (prevX || prevY) {
      let prevMinY = Math.round(prevY - size)
      let prevMaxY = Math.round(prevY + size)
      let prevMinX = Math.round(prevX - size)
      let prevMaxX = Math.round(prevX + size)

      for (let y = prevMinY; y < prevMaxY; y++){
        for (let x = prevMinX; x < prevMaxX; x++) {
          if (y < 0 || y > canvasHeight) continue
          else if (x < 0 || x > canvasWidth) continue
          else {
            let offset = y * 4 * canvasWidth + x * 4
            imageData.data[offset] = 255
            imageData.data[offset + 1] = 255
            imageData.data[offset + 2] = 255
            imageData.data[offset + 3] = 255
          }
        }
      }
    }

    let minY = Math.round(y - size) 
    let maxY = Math.round(y + size) 
    let minX = Math.round(x - size) 
    let maxX = Math.round(x + size) 

    for (let y = minY; y < maxY; y++){
      for (let x = minX; x < maxX; x++) {
        if (y < 0 || y > canvasHeight) continue
        else if (x < 0 || x > canvasWidth) continue
        else {
          let offset = y * 4 * canvasWidth + x * 4
          imageData.data[offset] = particle.color.r
          imageData.data[offset + 1] = particle.color.g
          imageData.data[offset + 2] = particle.color.b
          imageData.data[offset + 3] = particle.color.a
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  function init() {
    particleArray = []
    imageData = ctx.createImageData(canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
    // Initializing imageData to a blank white "page"
    for (let data = 1; data <= canvasWidth * canvasHeight * 4; data++) {
      imageData.data[data - 1] = data % 4 === 0 ? 255 : 255
    }

    const size = 2 // Min size is 2
    const step = Math.floor(size / 2)
    for (let y = 0, y2 = data.height; y < y2; y += step) {
      for (let x = 0, x2 = data.width; x < x2; x += step) {
        // If particle's alpha value is too low, don't record it
        if (data.data[(y * 4 * data.width) + (x * 4) + 3] > 128) {
          let newParticle = createParticle(x, y, size)
          particleArray.push(newParticle)
          updateImageDataWith(newParticle)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    
    for (let i = 0; i < particleArray.length; i++) {
      let imageDataCanUpdateKey = `${Math.round(particleArray[i].x)}${Math.round(particleArray[i].y)}`
      particleArray[i].update()

      updateImageDataWith(particleArray[i])
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
  }
  
  init()
  animate()
  
  window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
    canvas.width = innerWidth
    canvas.height = innerHeight
    canvasWidth = canvas.width
    canvasHeight = canvas.height
    init()
  })
}

const png = new Image()
png.src = " data:image/png;base64,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"

window.addEventListener('load', e => {
  // Ensuring height of image is always 100px
  let pngWidth = png.width
  let pngHeight = png.height
  
  let divisor = pngHeight / 100
  let finalWidth = pngWidth / divisor
  let finalHeight = pngHeight / divisor
  
  ctx.drawImage(png, 0, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight)
  drawImage(finalWidth, finalHeight)
})
```

```css
#canvas1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```

Comment: How is this different than my answer?

Comment: @DRAX How is it the same, though? A brief scan on your answer tells me that you are drawing each Particle per frame (`ctx.fillRect(...)`; called by `Particle.update`). My answer, on the other hand, computes the pixels that are to be generated by each Particle and places it inside an `ImageData` object before finally drawing it *the whole canvas once* (not the individual Particles) per frame using the supplied `ImageData`.